# 'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal command error in windows cmd

Tags: node.js

I am doing node js server setup to connect to mongoDB(mongolab).

I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pI9FSrP2Fyo tutorial.

I finished the setup until npm install -g nodemon command.
After typing the code when I typed nodemon server.js on the cmd I'm getting the error as below.

[image]

[image: server.js]

server.js

[image]

api.js

[image]

status.js

Comment: try installing it locally

Comment: there's nothing wrong with server.js

Comment: can u please help me to installing it locally. what do i need to do to install it locally?

Comment: set enviroment variable . this path C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm ... set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm; May be npm would have been install but not fetching path . Username is you name.

Comment: Try `npm i nodemon -g`

Comment: Sometimes you just have to restare explorer.exe before it recognises newly installed global node modules

Comment: i tried @Himanushu sharma. not working

Comment: Paste your code, as code not as an image - that way we can run it to, help you. I'm not typing all that out!! (from a quick glance it looks alright though)

Comment: Does it work fine, when you run it using `node` instead of `nodemon`?

Comment: Thank you @Lissy. It's working. Thank u so much

Comment: No problem, glad it's working :)

Answer (score 4):

d
Since node prefix is not in the PATH ENV variable , any of the globally installed modules are not getting recognized.

Please try this.

Open cmd prompt

npm config get prefix

append the resulting path to PATH env variable.

Now you should be able to run nodemon from any location.

This is what i have done on my local machine

```
C:\>npm config get prefix
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm;

C:\>nodemon
 31 Jul 22:30:29 - [nodemon] v0.7.8
 31 Jul 22:30:29 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
 31 Jul 22:30:29 - [nodemon] watching: C:\
 31 Jul 22:30:29 - [nodemon] starting `node `
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? Y
```

Comment: Sorry, but this solution is nort working for me. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Try **restarting explorer.exe** - it's a common issue in Windows, that environmental variables don't refresh automatically

Comment: node and nodemon are different though, node will run your node application, whereas nodemon will run your node application, and automatically refresh it after you've made a change. nodemon is a lifechanger when it comes to development!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install nodemon globally

```
npm install -g nodemon
# or if using yarn
yarn global add nodemon
```

if you want to use it locally then add in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "nodemon /path/to/your/main/script"
  },
```